# Tips to transform a simple program in continuation programming?

Tags: python, algorithm, continuations

For example I would like to do some NLP text treatment  : extract some keywords, and find correlation between them (with previous lemma-POS segmentation). 
The Pipeline would be :

```
    count all (lemmatised) words,  
    make a stopwords list,  
    use a RAKE-like algorithm to extract keyword list,  
    make some frequency-correlation matrix  the kw list content and/or the POS/lemma words...
```

For example in pseudo-python :

```
def count_words(infile,open_and_read) :  
    dic = {}  
    f = open_and_read(infile)  
    for word in f:   
      if word not in dic:   
           dic[word] = 1  
       else dic[word] +=1  
    return dic
```

etc etc

How do you transform this kind of pipeline in continuous programming ?

Comment: I don't think it's used much, but in a theoretical sense you can see if [this](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html) helps.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking – how about you help describe the problem you're trying to solve and worry less about what the code might look like? I'm certain you'll get better help with a better question ^_^